Combine grouped columns into one row
My current data looks like the following:
  Claimnumber  TaskName       CompleteDate       GroupNum
     123        Claim Creation  2024-01-01           1
     123        Incoming        2024-01-05           1
     123        Claim Creation  2024-02-01           2
     123        Incoming        2024-02-02           2
     234        Claim Creation  2024-03-24           1
     234        Incoming        2024-03-28           1

I'm trying to get records with the same clainumber and groupnum to be on one row:
  Claimnumber    TaskName1         TaskName2     CompleteDate1    CompleteDate2      Groupnum
       123          Claim Creation      Incoming    2024-01-01      2024-01-05           1
       123          Claim Creation      Incoming    2024-02-01      2024-02-02           2
       234          Claim Creation      Incoming    2024-03-24      2024-03-28           1

I've tried both pivot and string_agg but neither seems to work.  Am I on the right track or is there a better way?
  declare @t table
  (claimnumber int,
  taskname varchar(100),
  completedate datetime,      
  groupnum int)

  insert into @t
  values (123, 'Claim Creation', '01/01/2024',  1),
   (123, 'Incoming', '01/05/2024',  1),
   (123, 'Claim Creation', '02/01/2024',  2),
   (123, 'Incoming', '02/02/2024',  2),
   (234, 'Claim Creation', '03/24/2024',  1),      
   (234, 'Incoming', '03/28/2024',  1)
  

 select * 
 from @t

